# Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined when load multi model into Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I following this example 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/aggregate-multi-models-sequence-forge-viewer 
for loading multi model into Forge Viewer but sometimes I got this error:

> Cannot read property 'isEmpty' of undefined.

When i try to reload the page again sometime it don't have this error, i don't know why. Can you please help. Thank you very much
[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXkV2.png)

Comment: Could you share a code snippet reflecting the changes you made to the code inside the blog? Note. Please don't share your access token here, it's confidential info.

Comment: Or have a look on my modified version here https://github.com/yiskang/MultipleModelUtil

Comment: Hi Eason, i follow your new update and it work fine for me now. But i'm still have some errors on screen like this   **bold  " No access token is provided, but authorization requested. This is a problem. Logger.js:186 "**.  I'm using Jquery ajax for request token . It doesn't mater with me now, but do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my request for token

```
function getForgeToken(callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/token',
    success: function (res) {
      callback(res.access_token, res.expires_in)
    }
  });
}
```

And for Initialize [token error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abVJ5.png),  [Load failure error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ73n.png)

```
 var token  = getForgeToken;
  var options = {
                    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
                    getAccessToken: token 
                };

  //It looks the static function of Viewer does not support ES6
  //still use ES5
  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
              //get the viewer div
      const viewerDiv = document.getElementById( 'forgeViewerLocal' );

      //initialize the viewer object
      const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D( viewerDiv);

      //load model one by one in sequence
      const util = new MultipleModelUtil( viewer );
      util.processModels( models); 
   });

   launchViewer( models.concat() );
```

Comment: You have to call Forge OAuth API to obtain the access token from your backend, e.g. https://github.com/yiskang/forge-token-server

Comment: I fogot to add token for lunchViewer function. Thank you very much for your help !